# Fail to prove a permutation property

Tags: coq

I have created this simple type :

```
Inductive implist : nat -> list nat -> Prop :=
 | GSSingle    : forall (n:nat), implist n [n]
 | GSPairLeft  : forall (a b n:nat) (l:list nat), implist n l -> implist n ([a]++[b]++l)
 | GSPairRight : forall (a b n:nat) (l:list nat), implist n l -> implist n (l++[a]++[b]).
```

and I try to prove this permutation lemma :

```
Lemma permutImplist :
  forall (n a b c:nat) (input:list nat), implist n ((a::b::c::input)) <-> implist n ((c::b::a::input)).
```

I've tried various induction principles on the type itself or the list, but always end up in a dead end.

Can someone help me with this proof ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The induction principle of this predicate is not very useful for proving this directly. It is much better to find an alternative formulation of `implist` to make your proof go through:

```
From Coq Require Import List PeanoNat Lia.
Import ListNotations.

Inductive implist : nat -> list nat -> Prop :=
 | GSSingle    : forall (n:nat), implist n [n]
 | GSPairLeft  : forall (a b n:nat) (l:list nat), implist n l -> implist n ([a]++[b]++l)
 | GSPairRight : forall (a b n:nat) (l:list nat), implist n l -> implist n (l++[a]++[b]).

Lemma implist_alt n l :
  implist n l <->
  exists l1 l2,
    l = l1 ++ n :: l2 /\
    Nat.even (length l1) = true /\
    Nat.even (length l2) = true.
Proof.
split.
- intros H. induction H as [n|a b n l _ IH|a b n l _ IH].
  + exists [], []; intuition.
  + destruct IH as (l1 & l2 & -> & Hl1 & Hl2).
    exists (a :: b :: l1), l2; intuition.
  + destruct IH as (l1 & l2 & -> & Hl1 & Hl2).
    exists l1, (l2 ++ [a; b]). simpl.
    rewrite <- app_assoc, app_length, Nat.add_comm.
    intuition.
- intros (l1 & l2 & -> & Hl1 & Hl2).
  assert (Hb1 : exists b, length l1 < b) by (exists (S (length l1)); lia).
  destruct Hb1 as (b1 & Hb1).
  assert (Hb2 : exists b, length l2 < b) by (exists (S (length l2)); lia).
  destruct Hb2 as (b2 & Hb2).
  revert l1 b2 l2 Hl1 Hl2 Hb1 Hb2.
  induction (Nat.lt_wf_0 b1) as [b1 _ IH1].
  intros [| x1 [| y1 l1]]; simpl; try easy.
  + intros b2 l2 _ Hl2 _. revert l2 Hl2.
    induction (Nat.lt_wf_0 b2) as [b2 _ IH2].
    induction l2 as [|x2 l2 _] using rev_ind.
    * intros _ _. apply GSSingle.
    * induction l2 as [|y2 l2 _] using rev_ind; simpl; try easy.
      rewrite !app_length. simpl. rewrite <- Nat.add_assoc, Nat.add_comm. simpl.
      intros Hl2 Hb2. rewrite <- app_assoc.
      change (n :: l2 ++ [y2] ++ [x2]) with ((n::l2) ++ [y2] ++ [x2]).
      apply GSPairRight. apply (IH2 (S (S (length l2)))); eauto; lia.
  + intros b2 l2 Hl1 Hl2 Hb1 Hb2.
    apply (GSPairLeft x1 y1). apply (IH1 (S (S (length l1))) Hb1 _ b2); eauto.
Qed.

Lemma permutImplist_aux :
  forall (n a b c:nat) (input:list nat), implist n ((a::b::c::input)) -> implist n ((c::b::a::input)).
Proof.
intros n a b c l (l1 & l2 & e & Hl1 & Hl2)%implist_alt.
destruct l1 as [|x l1]; simpl in *.
{ injection e as <- <-; simpl in *.
  apply implist_alt. exists [c; b], l; intuition. }
destruct l1 as [|y l1]; simpl in *; try easy.
injection e as <- <- e.
destruct l1 as [|z l1]; simpl in *.
{ injection e as <- <-.
  apply implist_alt. exists [], (b :: a :: l); intuition. }
destruct l1 as [|w l1]; simpl in *; try easy.
injection e as <- ->.
apply implist_alt. exists (c :: b :: a :: w :: l1), l2.
intuition.
Qed.

Lemma permutImplist :
  forall (n a b c:nat) (input:list nat), implist n ((a::b::c::input)) <-> implist n ((c::b::a::input)).
Proof.
intros n a b c l; split; apply permutImplist_aux.
Qed.
```

The tricky part, as you can see, is the reverse direction of `implist_alt`. The ideal way of proving this would be to have an induction principle for lists of even length. Since we do not have this, I have instead used strong induction on the length of the even lists, which works fine as well.

Comment: Thank you ! Impressive ! In fact, I had created two induction principals for lists of even length for this proof, but obviously I didn't use them properly : one for induction 'on the left' and one for induction 'on the right'.

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice about the induction principal for even lists, I've been able to produce a shorter proof for the reverse direction part :

```
Lemma implist_alt' :
  forall (n:nat) (l:list nat), implist n l <-> exists l1 l2, l = l1 ++ n::l2 /\ Nat.Even (length l1) /\ Nat.Even (length l2).
Proof.
  split.
  - intros H. induction H as [n|a b n l _ IH|a b n l _ IH].
    + exists [], []; intuition; simpl; now exists 0.
    + destruct IH as (l1 & l2 & -> & Hl1 & Hl2).
      exists (a :: b :: l1), l2. intuition. simpl. now rewrite Nat.Even_succ_succ.
    + destruct IH as (l1 & l2 & -> & Hl1 & Hl2).
      exists l1, (l2 ++ [a; b]). simpl.
      rewrite <- app_assoc, app_length, Nat.add_comm.
      intuition. simpl. now rewrite Nat.Even_succ_succ.
  - intros (l1 & l2 & -> & Hl1 & Hl2).
    induction l1 using list_pair_induction.
    simpl. now apply (EvenImplist n l2).
    simpl in Hl1. rewrite Nat.Even_succ_succ in Hl1. apply IHl1 in Hl1. revert Hl1. now apply (GSPairLeft a b n (l1++n::l2)).
    simpl in Hl1. exfalso. now apply Even_1.
Qed.
```

It uses the following induction principal on lists :

```
Section list_pair_induction.

 Variable P : list nat -> Prop.

 Hypothesis Hnil  : P nil.
 Hypothesis Hddn  : forall (l:list nat) (a b:nat) , P l -> P (a::b::l).

 Theorem allEven : forall (xs:list nat), even (length xs) = true -> P xs.
 Proof.
  intro.
  remember (length xs) as n eqn : Heqn.
  revert n xs Heqn.
  induction n as [n IH] using (well_founded_induction lt_wf).
  destruct n as [|n].
   now destruct xs.
  destruct n as [|n].
   intros; discriminate.
  destruct xs as [|a xs].
   intros; discriminate.
  destruct xs as [|b xs].
   intros; discriminate.
  simpl.
  intros H1 H2.
  apply Hddn.
  apply IH with (y := n); auto.
  now injection H1.
 Qed.

 Theorem allEven' : forall (xs:list nat), Nat.Even (length xs) -> P xs.
 Proof.
  intro.
  rewrite <- Nat.even_spec.
  apply allEven.
 Qed.

 Hypothesis Hsingle : forall (n:nat), P (n::nil).

  Theorem Hsingle2Hsing : (forall n:nat, P(n::nil) ) -> forall (xs:list nat), (1 = length xs) -> P xs.
  Proof.
    induction xs.
    intro.
    exfalso.
    simpl in H0.
    congruence.
    induction xs.
    intro.
    apply Hsingle.
    intro.
    exfalso.
    simpl in H0.
    congruence.
  Qed.

  Theorem allOdd : forall (xs:list nat), odd (length xs) = true -> P xs.
  Proof.
    intro.
    remember (length xs) as n eqn : Heqn.
   revert n xs Heqn.
   induction n as [n IH] using (well_founded_induction lt_wf).
   destruct n as [|n].
    now destruct xs.
   destruct n as [|n].
    intros.
    generalize Heqn.
    generalize xs.
    generalize Hsingle.
    apply Hsingle2Hsing.
   destruct xs as [|a xs].
    intros; discriminate.
   destruct xs as [|b xs].
    intros; discriminate.
   simpl.
   intros H1 H2.
   apply Hddn.
   apply IH with (y := n); auto.
   now injection H1.
  Qed.
 
  Hypothesis Hsing  : forall (l:list nat) , (1 = length l) -> P (l).

 Theorem allOddsing : forall (xs:list nat), odd (length xs) = true -> P xs.
 Proof.
   intro.
   remember (length xs) as n eqn : Heqn.
  revert n xs Heqn.
  induction n as [n IH] using (well_founded_induction lt_wf).
  destruct n as [|n].
   now destruct xs.
  destruct n as [|n].
   intros.
   apply Hsing.
   assumption.
  destruct xs as [|a xs].
   intros; discriminate.
  destruct xs as [|b xs].
   intros; discriminate.
  simpl.
  intros H1 H2.
  apply Hddn.
  apply IH with (y := n); auto.
  now injection H1.
 Qed.

 Theorem allOdd' : forall (xs:list nat), Nat.Odd (length xs) -> P xs.
 Proof.
   intro.
   rewrite <- Nat.odd_spec.
   apply allOdd.
 Qed.

 Theorem list_pair_induction : forall (xs:list nat), P xs.
 Proof.
  intro.
  remember (length xs) as n eqn : Heqn.
  destruct even_odd_dec with n.
  apply allEven'.
  rewrite <- Heqn.
  assumption.
  apply allOdd'.
  rewrite <- Heqn.
  assumption.
 Qed.

End list_pair_induction.
```